# Find all functions such that $af(x-1)+bf(1-x)=cx$, where $a$,$b$ and $c$ are real and $a^2$ is not equal to $b^2$

Tags: functional-equations

I tried to find $f(0)$, by taking $x=1$,

$$f(0)=\frac{c}{a+b},$$

Then i deduced that $f(x)$ is linear,

Taking $x=(u+1), af(u)+bf(-u)=(u+1)c$

Similarly, $af(-u)+bf(u)=f(1-u)c$, adding them

$2c/(a+b)=f(u)+f(-u)$

Now take u+1,

$f(u+1)+f(-u-1)=2c/(a+b)$

Equating this with the first,

$f(u+1)-f(u)=f(-u)-f(-u-1)=2c/(a+b)$

this lead me to the conclusion that f(x) is linear,

Comment: If you have shown that $f(x)$ is linear then you know that $f(x)=Mx+B$ for two constants $M,B$.  Now you can just solve for $M,B$.

Comment: But note:  the function $F(x)=x^3$ satisfies $F(x)+F(-x)=0=2F(0)$ so I am not convinced you have shown that your function $f(x)$ is linear.

Comment: $f(x)=\frac c {a+b}$ is a non-zero solution.

Comment: @lulu Notice the condition $a^2\ne b^2$

Comment: @Qurultay  I didn't say that my $F(x)=x^3$ satisfied the OP's functional equation, I am just pointing out that knowing that $F(x)+F(-x)=2F(0)$ does not imply that $F(x)$ is linear, which appears to be a claim that the OP is making.

Comment: @user728189 From $af(u)+bf(-u)=(u+1)c$ you cannot conclude that $f$ is linear.

Comment: If $x=u+1$ then the functional equation gets us $af(u)+bf(-u)=c$.  I don't understand where the $u+1$ term on the right comes from (in your comment).

Comment: Taking $x=(u+1), af(u)+bf(-u)=(u+1)c, Also af(-u)+bf(u)=f(1-u)c, adding them , 2c/(a+b)=f(u)+f(-u), Now take u+1, f(u+1)+f(-u-1)=2c/(a+b), equating this with the first, f(u+1)-f(u)=f(-u)-f(-u-1)=2c/(a+b), this lead me to the conclusion that f(x) is linear

Comment: Did you write your functional equation correctly?

Comment: It is $cx$ on the right side,

Comment: Post edit:  most of the comments are now irrelevant.  But it is still true that knowing that a function $F(x)$ satisfies $F(x)+F(-x)=2F(0)$ does not imply that $F(x)$ is linear.

Comment: Check my previous long comment,

Comment: No.  Please edit your post to indicate your reasoning.   Don't leave detailed computations for the comments.

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  You don't mean $af(-u)+bf(u)=f(1-u)c$ for example.  And once again:  knowing that $F(x)+F(-x)=2F(0)$ does not imply linearity.

Comment: af(x-1)+b(1-x)=cx is the functional equation, i substituted x=u+1, to deduce that f(x) is linear

Answer (score 1):

Let $x-1=t.$
$$af(x-1)+bf(1-x)=cx \implies af(t)+bf(-t)=c(t+1)~~~(1).$$
Let $t\rightarrow -t$; we get
$$af(-t)+bf(t)=c(-t+1)~~~(2)$$
Let $f(t)=X, f(-t)=Y$, then we have $aX+bY=ct+c, aY+bX=-ct+c$
Solve for $X$ 
$$X=f(t)=c[\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{t}{a-b}]\implies f(x-1)=c[\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{(x-1)}{a-b}]$$
Finally $$f(x)=c[\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{x}{a-b}]$$

Comment: Why do you have those brackets?